The proper way to upload a image behind Uri received from the PickVisualMediaRequest
I'm using PickVisualMediaRequest to get an Uri of a selected file:
For example:

content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000008579

ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(new PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
    if (uri != null) {
        // 
        uploadToServer(uri);
    }
});

pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
    .setMediaType(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
    .build());

No I have no idea how now to upload the file.
I have seen many hacks and workarounds, but I suspect that there is certainly a simple method.
I know that I can get InputStream using ContentProvider, but it is not enough for me, because I need the name of the file or at least the type of the file to be able to store it correctly on the server (By using OkHttp / MultiPart). So the best I need is File object. But how do I get a file object from a Uri?

"I need the name of the file" -- the user may not have chosen a file on the filesystem. Use DocumentFile.fromSingleUri() to get a DocumentFile based on the Uri that you receive. You can use that to get a display name (which may or may not be a filename) and a MIME type for the content.
